Flag emoji looks faded in country_picker
flag is looking faded. I am using country_picker plugin. (https://pub.dev/packages/country_picker)  how to show flag brighter???

 showCountryPicker(
                          countryListTheme: CountryListThemeData(
                            bottomSheetHeight:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
                            flagSize: isMobile ? 25 : 40,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          context: context,
                          showPhoneCode: true,
                          onSelect: (country) {
                          });
                    },


Can you please share the code for flag? Like somewhere you have used image path

Your code is  working well and Flag image is also display as per this

I checked in android device and ios simulator it looks faded
country_picker: ^2.0.20 @RavindraS.Patil

Any changes you made?

@Flutterian   Widget _flagWidget(Country country) {     final bool isRtl = Directionality.of(context) == TextDirection.rtl;     return SizedBox(       // the conditional 50 prevents irregularities caused by the flags in RTL mode       width: isRtl ? 50 : null,       child: Text(         country.iswWorldWide             ? '\uD83C\uDF0D'             : Utils.countryCodeToEmoji(country.countryCode),         style: TextStyle(           fontSize: widget.countryListTheme?.flagSize ?? 25,         ),       ),     );   }

@Nandhini Ravichandran no I don't made any changes, use your above code

@NandhiniRavichandran I think As per package implementation you don't need flagWidget()

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
